# Logitech update stuck in Ubuntu store update page

Tags: updates, ubuntu-store

I have an update stuck in the Ubuntu store, when I click update, nothing happens.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Ignore it. Update using the Updates tool or in terminal.

Comment: Is there any way to remove it from the updates list ?

Comment: Sorry, don't know. I don't usually waste time with non issues.

Comment: This is not a non issue. This update is not available via apt. If you really can, please provide the instructions for a terminal installation.

Answer (score 0):

Information about this update can be seen at https://community.logitech.com/s/question/0D531000055gw8YCAQ/logitech-response-to-unifying-receiver-research-findings. It resolves a firmware issue that could allow a hacker access to your computer.

However, the update requires a Windows computer to install it, so I don't understand why it's appearing in the (Linux) Software Store. If you don't have a Logitech Unifying Receiver, ignore it. If you do have one, download the update in Windows and apply it.